# JHipster - How to handle Keycloak Login Error

Tags: keycloak, jhipster

I'm using JHipster gateway with Keycloak as identity provider.

Sometimes an error occurs during the Keycloak login process. Keycloak then routes me back to the gateway with this path: https://my-gateway-url/login?error.

The gateway doesn't show a login error page, but instead shows the following:

```json
{
    "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "status": 401,
    "detail": "Not Authenticated",
    "path": "/login",
    "message": "error.http.401"
}
```

Is there a way to let the gateway show a custom error page when keycloak redirects to `/login?error`, or if not, possibly a simple way to change the redirect logic in Keycloak so that it doesn't redirect to `/login?error`?

I'm not so clued up with how /login is handled within the gateway.

I have tried to play around with SpaWebFilter.java to force a redirect to /error/login where I have a custom error page, but it did not work and gave the same error as previous.

```java
public class SpaWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    /**
     * Forwards any unmapped paths (except those containing a period) to the client {@code index.html}.
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath();
        String query = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getQuery();
         if (
            !path.startsWith("/api") &&
            !path.startsWith("/management") &&
            !path.startsWith("/login") &&
            !path.startsWith("/services") &&
            !path.startsWith("/v3/api-docs") &&
            path.matches("[^\\\\.]*")
        ) {
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(exchange.getRequest().mutate().path("/index.html").build()).build());
        } else if(path.startsWith("/login") && query != null && query.equals("error")) {
             return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(exchange.getRequest().mutate().path("/error/login").build()).build());
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```